# Where are examples for the latest Neo4j codebase?

Tags: neo4j

http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/
... seems old.
Section 4.2 points to a dead link.

Starting with version 3.0, I can't find examples on github.
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/3.0/community

Where are they?

Comment: 3.2 is still in alpha version i doubt that there is documentation yet ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link to the java reference should be current for 3.1. As far as the broken link, there's a `/manual/` part of the path which really shouldn't be there, try [this](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-documentation/blob/3.1/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java) instead.

Comment: Why doesn't maven compile it? Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:parent:pom:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 11 -> [Help 2]